# Upgrade to SSL using StreamSocket

Tags: c#, ssl, xmpp, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am working on WinRT(Windows8 Release Preview). I have a web application(in fact, a simpler XMPP Client).

I mainly  use StreamSocket class to connect the Jabber Server. It gives me a good start.But I met a problem when i try to upgrade the already connected socket to use SSL.

I use [StreamSocket.UpgradeToSslAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket.UpgradeToSslAsync%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) to implement it.  It throws exception like this

> A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8000000E)

I have no idea why this happen. I have done all thing  as the above link. I have created the socket connecting successfully. And I can receive some xml stanzas from Jabber server.
Here is a picture when it runs.![enter image description here][1]

You can see the picture in a [new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dofSC.jpg).

When I click the UpToSSL button, it crashes and throw the exception as above.

Here is simpler version code:

```
 // xmpp is my  CXMPP  client class
 private void StartTlsBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   xmpp.SendXml("<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls' />");            
 } 
 // it works fine, and i have got the reponse from server:
 //     <proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
 // next step i should upgrade my sockey connection to ssl

    private void UpSslBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      xmpp.UpToSsl();         
    }

    async public void UpToSsl()
    {
        SendEvent.WaitOne();
        SendEvent.Reset();

        // private StreamSocket ClientSock;
        await ClientSock.UpgradeToSslAsync(SocketProtectionLevel.Ssl, ClientSock.Information.RemoteHostName);
        isSsl = true;
        SendEvent.Set();
    }
```

Please give me some tips. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with ConnectAsync? It would help if you showed how you create the socket and implement the steps in the Remarks section of the docs.

Comment: Yes, actually  i use ConnectAsync as MSDN says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on an XMPP application for Metro as well, the server connection and the protocol parser are ready.

I am using three ManualResetEvents so Send, Receive and Elevate won't collide. Also be carefull as UpgradeToSslAsync dosn't accept self-signed certificates, and in that case will throw an exception.

I would really like to help you further but I try to finance myself with this, the XMPP library will be released after the application is released in the store

Comment: Thank you all the same. Do you mean  my problem is caused by my local  certificate ?  Can you give me some tips or key words?

Comment: The exception is because there is a Read or Write in progress, I close my DataReader and DataWriter first, after that I try to elevate, the exception for an invalid certificate looks different

Comment: Paul, you are right, if i use the UpgradeToSslAsync before starting the receive thread, it works well. That means this function can work.

Comment: Paul, you are right. if i use the UpgradeToSslAsync before starting the receive thread, it works well. That means this function can work.     It is caused by the Read and Write Event. I run a recevie thread in background (it never stops). And i use the   ManualResetEvents  ReceiveEvent to make sure it won't collide with other operation. But if there is no data in the network, then the ReceiveEvent won't be set. In this case, some operation which is waiting this semaphore will block there. My UpToSsl() now is a example as this case.